# Sync android sqlite db and sql server in one way

Tags: android, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I am developing an android application which have sqlite db on my device and sql server db on the main machine, the android device contain very small part of main db, so i don't want to replicate whole db. and I have my own webserver that upload/download data between databases,
my question is how I know which part of main database is changed to only download changed entries?

Comment: Put a `dateTime` filed. If the row is modified change time to the date modified. This way you will keep track which and when the data has been changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One usefull technique is using [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) data type. You can see it as the server change number. You can get the current change number by using the  [MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx) function. Then query from changes occurred form last downloaded change number to current change number and finally store the current change number as the last downloaded change number in the local SQLite database.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentServerChange binary(8)
SET @CurrentServerChange = MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE 
    RecordVersion >= @LastDownloadedChangeNumber
    AND RecordVersion < @CurrentServerChange 

SELECT * FROM Table3
WHERE 
    RecordVersion >= @LastDownloadedChangeNumber
    AND RecordVersion < @CurrentServerChange 

SELECT @CurrentServerChange AS CurrentServerChange
```

I assume `RecordVersion` columns are of type `rowversion`